# Using node.js module on jsfiddle

Tags: node.js, jsfiddle, cryptojs

I have working algorithm on my own project and I need it to be uploaded on jsfiddle and working as expected. The bad thing is I have no idea how to use [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) to work there.

```
this.getOffset = function(forcedOffset){
    return Bluebird.try(function () {
        if (forcedOffset != undefined) return forcedOffset;

        return CryptoJS.randomBytes(4);
    }).then(function (randomBytes) {
        var random = Number.parseInt(randomBytes.toString('hex'), 16) / 4294967295;
        var maxVal = 1000000;
        return Math.floor(random * maxVal);
    });
};
```

and for my project I'm just requiring it, but how to handle this situation here?

Comment: Load it as an external resource from a CDN.

Comment: and where can I find it uploaded to CDN? because i tried to load this one [crypto-js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js) but didn't figured out how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find it on a CDN and load it.

After googling "cryptojs cdn" i found this list of the resources

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js

Comment: and how to use it loading this [lib](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/aes.js) ? how the variable will be called?

Comment: documentation of what? I just can't understand how to use functions of this module on  jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

crypto-js can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js). Using [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com) you can load any file from any package following this pattern

```
https://unpkg.com/:package@:version/:file
```

So, if you add

```
https://unpkg.com/crypto-js@4.0.0/
```

Then you'll get [this](https://unpkg.com/crypto-js@4.0.0/) (as shown in the next image)

[image: UNPKG npm package in JSFiddle]

If you specify the index.js file

```
https://unpkg.com/crypto-js@4.0.0/index.js
```

Then you'll get [this](https://unpkg.com/crypto-js@4.0.0/index.js) (as shown in the next image)

[image: JSFiddle with npm packages]

You'll then be able to use it in your fiddles by adding the Resources you want to.